# I have a problem with python Django 'Login' has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django, filter

I made a website with python Django. My models are two which called 'Login' and 'Ch'.

And my website has 'signup' and 'home' page. The 'signup' page is literally signup page. User can register his/her ID and password. Then these information save in 'id' and 'pw' in the 'Login' model.

Now, Typing his/her ID and password, user can login through 'home' page. This is my plan. However, the login process consistently happen problem with the sentence 'Login' has no attribute 'filter'.

My partial code is

```
log = Login.objects.all() 
try: 
  ch = log.filter(id = request.POST["login_id"], pw = ghv(request.POST["login_pw"])) #ghv is user definition function for get hash value of password
   if (ch): 
       id = request.POST["login_id"] 
       return render(request,'pdg/home2.html') 
   else: 
       return render(request, "pdg/home_e.html") 
except ObjectDoesNotExist: 
  return render(request, "pdg/home_e.html")
```

Signup process has no problem. I think that after signup process complete, Being added the user data in 'Login' model is cause the problem. Because restarting the runserver is effective for solving this error. However I want to find a solution for this error without restarting the runserver.

Please help me.. And THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ch = Login.objects.filter(login_id=login_Id, login_pw=login_pw)

Comment: How simple solution it is!! Thanks to you, I've solved this problem!! Thank you again!